# Taking a screenshot through code in a Javascript MS Store UWP app

Tags: javascript, html, css, uwp

I am working on a MS Store UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app built using only Javascript, CSS and HTML.

I need to take a screenshot of the app at any given time through code but I cant seem to find any relevant api (or method) to do so. 
Although, there is an api given in UWP docs regarding this (in C#) but its usage through javascript is not available. 
Any help will be great.

/Thanks,

Jatin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots)

Answer (score 2):

This question can help you: [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots).
But actually you could have spent more time on your research and not spam duplicate questions.

Comment: I have tried html2canvas but you would already know that it does not allow screenshots of flash, etc. elements. Hence, it is of no use to me.
Also, I was looking for a much specific method for windows uwp js apps.

Comment: By the way, Jack I thought discussing about my problems with my fellow programmers is also a part of effective research , isn't it?

Comment: And did you even read the docs? UWP has a namespace that provides an API to capture the screen. They even have an article about it. Think you can convert it to JavaScript if you need it: [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture)

Comment: Jack, the usage of Screen.capture through JS is not available. That was the help I was looking for.